# how to use createSlice's RTK function to create a state that has multiple properties?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux-Toolkit in a React project to manage the state of my app. I created a slice for customers. A customer is an object that possesses a name, id, list of food, number of guests accompanying them, the location of the restaurant, and the order's date and time.

In `createSlice`, what code should I write exactly to add all these properties to the state?

I took this project from someone else and initially, the customers' state had only an id, name, and array of food.
Now I want to add the other properties as well.
Here is the Customer Interface:

```js
export interface Customer {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  food: string[];
}
```

And here is the code of the customerSlice:

```js
export const customerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "customer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addCustomer: (state, action: PayloadAction<Customer>) => {
      state.value.push(action.payload);
    },
    addFoodToCustomer: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<AddFoodToCustomerPayload>
    ) => {
      state.value.forEach((customer) => {
        if (customer.id === action.payload.id) {
          customer.food.push(action.payload.food);
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

How do I add these properties to the state?

```js
guestsNumber: number | string;
restauLocation: string;
orderDate: string;
orderTime: string;
```

Comment: Do you need to add these properties to the `Customer` interface, or do you need to add it to the `initialState` value? Is it not enough to simply update the `Customer` interface to include these fields/properties? What exactly is the issue or problem you have? What have you tried? Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: I am new to Redux, so let me explain: in principle, each customer has these properties: name, a list of food, the number of guests accompanying him, the location of the restaurant, and the order's date and time. I want all these fields' states to be managed by RTK.So, do I need to add them to the initalState, if so, how? Or do I need to add them to the Customer interface and that would be all? for these additional fields, I created React components where they will be used, for example, I created a React component named 'GuestsCounter', in which a state variable must be used to control the stat

Comment: e of the input being returned in the JSX:   `const [guests, setGuests] = useState<number | string>(0);`
so, how to manage all these fields with RTK or there is no need to, and then each component must hold the appropriate state variable declared in a useState clause?

Comment: I see, then yes, you update the `Customer` interface to add those properties, and update the `initialState` if necessary.

Comment: and how to update the initialState ? and apart from updating the initialState, should I add some other code ?

Comment: You'd update `initialState` to have have initial values that satisfy the interface, likely just empty strings for the four new properties. If you need more help than this could you [edit] to add the `initialState` declaration? You *might* need to add other code if you need to update or specifically select these other properties.

Comment: Hey, here is the insialState's code : `export interface CustomerState {
  value: Customer[];
}

const initialState: CustomerState = {
  value: [],
};`  , and what code do I need to add so that I can update or select these new 4 properties' values when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the new fields/properties to the `Customer` interface.

```js
export interface Customer {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  food: string[];
  guestsNumber: number | string; // <-- new property
  restauLocation: string;        // <-- new property
  orderDate: string;             // <-- new property
  orderTime: string;             // <-- new property
}
```

I also suggest giving the state better property names, e.g. `state.customers` is ***much*** more informative than `state.value`. The `initialState` doesn't really need to have anything new since it's just an array of `Customer` objects. New actions can be created and can access/modify any `Customer` properties, e.g. the example `someNewAction` action below.

Example:

```js
export interface CustomerState {
  customers: Customer[];
}

const initialState: CustomerState = {
  customers: [],
};

export const customerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "customer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addCustomer: (state, action: PayloadAction<Customer>) => {
      state.customers.push(action.payload);
    },
    addFoodToCustomer: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<AddFoodToCustomerPayload>
    ) => {
      const { id, food } = action.payload;

      const customer = state.customers.find(customer => customer.id === id);

      if (customer) {
        customer.food.push(food);
      };
    },
    ...
    someNewAction: (state, action<.....>) => {
      const { id, guestNumber, location, ...etc... } = action.payload;

      const customer = state.customers.find(customer => customer.id === id);

      if (customer) {
        customer.guestsNumber = guestNumber;
        customer.restauLocation = location;
        ...
      };
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will try this tomorrow and I will let you know if I have any extra questions or face any other issue

Comment: and do I need this state variable `const [guests, setGuests] = useState<number | string>(0)` in GuestsCounter component to handle the guests' state or I would rather call inside GuestsCounter component and then use the new property 'guestsNumber' declared in the interface ?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK I think that depends largely on the UI/UX you need. If you need a local copy in a component to edit, *and then* later "submit/commit" changes to the Redux store, e.g. like a user editing fields in a form and submitting it, then using the local state makes sense. If the UI/UX is just to edit the data in the store directly, e.g. onChange handlers directly dispatching actions, then the local state might not be so necessary. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hey, I created addLocationToCustomer action in customerSlice component: `addLocationToCustomer: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<AddLocationToCustomerPayload>
    ) => {
      const { id, location } = action.payload;

      const customer = state.customers.find((customer) => customer.id === id);

      if (customer) {
        customer.restauLocation = location;
      }
    }`

Comment: now, in LocationSelect component, I added this line of code: `addLocationToCustomer({ location: location.label, id: "" });`
 to this function : `function handleLocationChange(
    newValue: SingleValue<{ value: string; label: string }> | any
  ): void {
    // console.log(newValue, "newValue");
    setLocation(newValue);
    addLocationToCustomer({ location: location.label, id: "" });
  }` . I am not using any form to submit these fields to some backend or something, I just one to retrieve these values and then use them later in other components.

Comment: So the line of code I added on handleLocationChange does make sense? I really don't know how I can use these new actions in the app's components, can you give me an example?

Comment: in LocationSelect component, there is this state variable : const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    value: "",
    label: "Select the restaurant's address",
  });

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK The action needs to be ***dispatched*** to the store, e.g. `dispatch(addLocationToCustomer({ location: location.label, id: "" }))`.

Comment: ah yeah you are right ! but I really need you to give me an example of how to access these props globally without having to pass them as props from a component to another. In CustomersSection component I have this JSX in return statement : `{customers.map((customer: Customer, index: number) => {
            return (
              <CustomerCard
                id={customer.id}
                foodList={customer.food}
                {...{ index }}
                restauLocation={customer.restauLocation}
              />
            );
          })}`

Comment: With     `dispatch(addLocationToCustomer({ location: location?.label, id: id }));` in `handleLocationChange` function the property restauLocation is now equal to location.label of `const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    value: "",
    label: "Select the restaurant's address",
  })` , so is there a way of accessing restauLocation prop from any component of the app's tree without having to pass it down as props ?

Comment: and we both know that setLocation function of useState clause updates the location's value, so how to do such a thing with redux toolkit ?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK All the customer data is in the Redux store, you can use the `useSelector` to select the customer state, and if you need to access a specific customer's data you can write a selector function that takes a customer id value and searches the customers array. There shouldn't be much to need to pass around in props.

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK BTW these follow-on questions are a bit off-topic for this post. If you have other questions or issues after getting your state updated following this post/answer it would be better to create a new SO post and include a [mcve] of the UI code you are working with. If you create a new post with new details feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: can I ask you one more question? when I refresh the page, the data kept in the store's state is lost, for example, the number of guests is reset to 0 ... in order for the data to still be there when I refresh the page, I think I must build some backend with an API, and store this data in some DB, and then fetch it from that API every time the app is run, right?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK You could persist it to localstorage. There's even a `redux-persist` library for this.

Comment: OK THANKS, A LOT ! But normally in a full stack application case scenario, the source of the data is a backend endpoint, so there is no need to use redux-persist in that case, since the data will stay in the UI even if we refresh the page, right?

Comment: and can I use both RTK and context API in the same React app to handle the state? RTK would be used to create a global state which lives in a dedicated store, and context will be used to pass down props from parent components to children, thus making it possible to avoid props drilling. I know that RTK is meant to also prevent props drilling, but in this example : `const customers: Customer[] = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.customerReducer.customers
  ); `

Comment: customers array is declared in App component, which has a nested component : `<CustomersSection {...{ customers }} />`, now in this component , we have in the return statement : ` <div className="customers-section-customers__list">
          {customers.map((customer: Customer, index: number) => {
            return (
              <CustomerCard
                id={customer.id}
                name={customer.name}
                foodList={customer.food}
                restauLocation={customer.restauLocation}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>`

Comment: to avoid passing the props name or foodList... to nested components, can't I do something like: `{customers.map((customer: Customer, index: number) => {
            return (<CustomerContext.Provider value={{ customer }}<CustomerCard /></CustomerContext.Provider>
            );
          })}?` of course assuming that I have created the context with `export const CustomerContext = createContext();
`... now, we this technique, there is no need to pass all those props to <CustomerCard /> component, I can access any attribute of the customer object in child components when I need to.Right?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK The frontend app state is effectively just another cache. Persisting the store to localStorage is a way to keep the cache around longer so you won't necessarily need to refetch ***all*** of the data ***every*** time the app mounts or the page reloads. Sure, you can use Redux and any number of React Contexts.

Comment: okay thanks, but can you please answer this question also: if I build a backend API while using a DB technology like MongoDB or Postgres to store the data in this DB, will I still have to use redux-persis to persist the state or there is no need to because the data will be fetched from the backend and will be available to be rendered on the UI every time the user refreshes the page?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK That depends entirely on the UX you want and how much network traffic you want to create or handle. It can vary depending on app needs. You could persist nothing and refetch everything every time if that is necessary, or you could cache/persist everything and only occasionally "check-in"/refetch data. Or anything between, like persisting auth state and basic necessary data, and always fetching on-demand content that updates in the backend often. Does this make sense? There's no one single solution for all.

Comment: yep it makes sens ! thanks a lot sir

Comment: and can you tell me how deep down can I pass props from parent to children components without running into issues and without bloating the app with props? what is recommended by the React community in these regards? I once read somewhere that it's okay to pass down data from a parent to 3 or 4 of its nested child components, but beyond that, it becomes harder to read and maintain code, and to reuse components, is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254661/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-abdelmounim-sifelhak).

Comment: Hi Reese, I need help with another issue, please! go to chat.